# Setup up Eclipse for android

Tags: android, eclipse

I am just beginning to understand programming and over the past few days I have been trying to properly set-up my Android Eclipse to start programming. I also tried to install cocos2dx but still with no success. My question is - How do I properly set Eclipse for android and any additional things like cocos2dx to start making a game for example like Flappy bird or something like that? Do I need anything special for it?

Comment: There are hundreds of videos for setting things up for Android. If you downloaded the regular version of Eclipse, don't use it. Google has put together everything you need in a special Eclipse bundle [here](http://developer.android.com/sdk/index.html). You can follow their instructions. Just make sure before you start you have the Java jdk installed. Then once you boot up that special version of Eclipse, launch the SDK manager to download the necessary tools for whatever Android OS version you want to develop for.

Comment: I know that I found the Full Bundle but do I need anything else to make a game like flappy bird in eclipse? Do I need cocos2dx or something like that.

Comment: It would be much easier to do with a physics engine/library yes. I was able to successfully make a game similar to flappy bird using [libgdx](http://libgdx.badlogicgames.com/)

Comment: Do I need the ADT Bundle with eclipse to use the Libgdx?

Comment: You need the Android SDK and an IDE to develop and since the ADT bundles those together, I'd say it's best. You could get away with just using another IDE and the Android SDK, but the ADT makes it easier. Libgdx is a library to be integrated. I believe they do have a special program that creates a default project within Eclipse after you download Libgdx.

Comment: I have three folders one is called flappyproject other flappyproject-android and the last one flappyproject-desktop. Which one Do i have to build my application in? and why Do i have 3 folders

Comment: That's how libgdx sets it up, you can run it as a desktop application or as an android app, but the folder called flappyproject is where you develop everything. Please search for a youtube tutorial about how to make a 2d platformer with libgdx on android, they'll be much more helpful as it's been a while since I've done this.

Comment: Does it have to be done using libgdx can I use something else?

Comment: There are plenty of physics engines available for android. Look up which one suits you best.

Comment: Why not go the Unity3D way?

Answer (score 0):

Libgdx, in my opinion, is the way to go. Even Cornell University use it for their game programming courses. See here for their advice on the matter

http://www.cs.cornell.edu/courses/cs4152/2014sp/materials/android.php

And, here is a link to get you going

http://www.kilobolt.com/zombie-bird-tutorial-flappy-bird-remake.html

It uses libgdx extensively.

Answer (score 0):

For game development you can consider something like Corona SDK. You can create a cross platform game which would run on iOS, Android and even Windows Phone.

More information here: http://coronalabs.com/products/corona-sdk/

If you would like to stick with Android, then I recommend to use Android Studio rather than Eclipse. Google gave up on Eclipse and actively moving towards the Android Studio:

https://developer.android.com/sdk/installing/studio.html

Games development is not straight forward. Maybe you should consider to learn application development first? Udacity has put a course together with Google, which can help you to understand how Android development works:

https://www.udacity.com/course/ud853

You also mentioned that you are new to programming. You should probably start with a lower level then Android development. Maybe start from learning Java?

https://www.udacity.com/course/cs046